# Combine two subqueries to main query in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL and need assistance to combine (JOIN) two subqueries with a main query in SQL. Here is what I have. *Each query works independent of another. The end result would be that I would retrieve the # of accommodations for each resort, retrieve the lowest cost of all accommodations for each resort, and join those results to the list of resort types and resorts.

DB Schema

```
Table 1 - Resort - 
            resort_id (PK)
            resort_type_id (FK)
            name
Table 2 - Resort_type - 
            resort_type_id (PK)
            resort_type
Table 3 - Accommodations - 
            accommodations_id (PK)
            resort_id (FK)
            description
            cost_per_night
```

Query

```
SELECT Resort.name, Resort_type, Acc.Accommodations, Low.min_price
FROM 
(SELECT resort.name AS resort_name, Resort_type.resort_type
FROM Resort
INNER JOIN Resort_type
ON Resort.resort_type_id = Resort_type.resort_type_id

(SELECT resort_id, Count(resort_id) AS Accommodations
FROM   Accommodations
GROUP  BY resort_id) AS Acc

(SELECT resort_id, Min(cost_per_night) AS min_price
FROM   Accommodations
GROUP  BY resort_id) AS Low
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I am having a difficult time visualizing how this should come together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query below lists each resort and its type along with the number of accommodations and the lowest cost per night.

```
select
  r.name,
  t.resort_type as type,
  count(a.accommodations_id) as accommodations,
  min(cost_per_night) as lowestcost
from resort r
inner join resort_type t
  on t.resort_type_id = r.resort_type_id
left join accommodations a
  on a.resort_id = r.resort_id
group by r.name, t.resort_type
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc089/6

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
    r.name,
    rt.resort_type,
    t.no_of_accommodations,
    t.min_price
FROM Resort r
INNER JOIN Resort_Type rt
    ON rt.resort_type_id = r.resort_type_id
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS no_of_accommodations,
        MIN(cost_per_night) AS min_price
    FROM Accommodations
    GROUP BY resort_id
)t
    ON t.resort_id = r.resort_id
```